# Greedy best-first Search Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, search, greedy

I can't understand why the worst-case time complexity of greedy best-first search is O(b^m).

In my opinion, greedy best-first search doesn't allow to track back, right? This means that the nodes can only get expanded deeper and deeper. So basically, there should be only one path after i run this algorithm, even if the path is incorrect. (because it is incomplete)

Am i right? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: [Best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) is a search algorithm; it won't give you a incorrect solution if there is a correct one. The greedy part doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to review how a [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) works. It takes a step based on (for example) an heuristic, but can come back to reconsider that later if it doesn't find a solution. That's why it's a "best-first" not a "best-only" search. This means that backtracking can happen, which you need to take into your analysis.